# kubernetes nginx ingress error with configuration-snippet

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have following ingress.yaml file

```sh
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: nginx-configuration-snippet
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          location /base/path/v1/api/update {
              deny all;
              return 404;
            }
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /base/path(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: myApi
              servicePort: 8080
```

But when I send a request to https:///base/path/v1/api/update it succeeds and I got following error in nginx ingress controller

```
Error: exit status 1
2020/08/06 18:35:07 [emerg] 1734#1734: location "/base/path/v1/api/update" is outside location "^/base/path(/|$)(.*)" in /tmp/nginx-cfg008325631:2445
nginx: [emerg] location "/base/path/v1/api/update" is outside location "^/base/path(/|$)(.*)" in /tmp/nginx-cfg008325631:2445
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg008325631 test failed
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [configuration-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) is to add configs **to locations**.

If you want to add a custom location to the [server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) context, you should use the [server-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) instead:

> Using the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` it is
> possible to add custom configuration in the server configuration
> block.

You also need to use some modifiers and regex to make it work (`~*` and `^`).

The following config should work:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: nginx-configuration-snippet
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          location ~* "^/base/path/v1/api/update" {
              deny all;
              return 403;
            }
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /base/path(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: myApi
              servicePort: 8080
```

The final `nginx.config` should end like this:

```
$ kubectl exec -n kube-system nginx-ingress-controller-6fc5bcc8c9-chkxf -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

[...]

location ~* "^/base/path/v1/api/update" {
            deny all;
            return 403;
        }
        
location ~* "^/base/path(/|$)(.*)" {
[...]           
}
```

Comment: wow ! that worked like a charm. Whole internet searched and your answer is the only thing helpful :)

Comment: @voidMainReturn can i use **configuration-snippet** like this `ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:`? I have this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858553/how-do-i-use-ingress-with-basic-auth-but-only-for-certain-routes)