# Problem with NGINX Ingress Controller auth-signin and server-snippet with error_page for custom error redirects

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, oauth2-proxy

I am trying to redirect from default NGINX error pages to custom error pages without customising the default backend as follows:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        error_page 404 "https://example.com/404";
        error_page 403 "https://example.com/403";
```

This works fine.

However, adding the auth-signin flag cancels the functionality:

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri`

I would expect the HTTP codes to still be identified after the OAuth2Proxy redirection and the error_page directive to still be applied.

Is there a way I could achieve this without releasing a custom default backend?

So far, I tried a couple of approaches:

1 ) Adding proxy_intercept_errors on;
2 ) Modifying nginx.conf inside the nginx pod
3 ) Adding custom-http-errors (I learned already this is not what i am after)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Replacing `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` solves this issue.

This answer helped me better understand the difference between the two: [kubernetes nginx ingress error with configuration-snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289848/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-error-with-configuration-snippet)